# $L(P,f) = -U(P,g)$ and $U(P,f) = -L(P,g)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function which is integrable on $[a,b]$ and let $g:=-f$. Show that for any partition $P$ we have $L(P,f) = -U(P,g)$ and $U(P,f) = -L(P,g).$

I've been thinking about this problem for a little while now and I suspect that I just have to ravel through the definitions right and use the fact that $\inf(S) = -\sup(-S)$ as follows?

Note that clearly $g$ is integrable over $[a,b]$ too.

So we are working with some partition $P$ of the interval $[a,b]$ with say $n$ elements. Denote $\Delta x_i = x_i-x_{i-1}$ for $i = 1,2,3,..., n$. We'll use the same partition for both $f$ and $g$.

So, given $f$ is integrable; $L(P,f) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}m_i\Delta x_i$ (Lower Darboux Sum of $f$), where

$m_i = \inf\{f(x)|x_{i-1}\le x \le x_i\}$

$= -\sup\{-f(x)|x_{i-1}\le x \le x_i\}$

$= -\sup\{g(x)|x_{i-1}\le x \le x_i\}$

$= -M_i $ and since $-U(P,g) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(-)M_i\Delta x_i$ (Upper Darboux Sum of $g$) we quickly conclude that $-U(P,g) = L(P,f)$. I'd form a similar argument for the other equality.

Perhaps I'm including confusion with variables? (Given $M_i$ is used to define the Upper Darboux sum of f too).

Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: There is no need to assume that $f$ is integrable, rather we need only that $f$ is bounded. And your idea is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The proof is correct but you cannot use $m_i$ and $M_i$ for both $f$ and $g$. Maybe, given a bounded function $h$ write $m_i(h):=\inf_{[x_{i-1},x_i]} h$ and $M_i(h):=\sup_{[x_{i-1},x_i]} h$. Then you proved that $m_i(f)=-M_i(g)$ and so $L(P,f)=-U(P,g)$.